# No available resource after deploy on docker my app

Tags: .net, docker, model-view-controller, dockerfile, docker-container

I containerize my app by using docker and after deploy I encounter problem with missing resources - no css and js files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5gBy.png)

docker compose file:

```
  my-app:
    image: my-app-img
    container_name: my-app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /MyApp

COPY . ./

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /MyApp
COPY --from=build-env /MyApp/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.WebUI.dll']
```

the links in layout

```
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

in program.cs im using the

app.UseStaticFiles();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my issue

for ex.

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();

DbHelpers.CreateDbIfNotExists(app);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Metrics/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Metrics}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

I moved the app.UseStaticFiles under our obj app, before that it was placed between app.usehttps / app.UseRouting and that caused this problem.